# 256 SSD / 2TB Internal drive, i7, 16GB RAM.. explorer.exe still slow

Tags: ssd

OK, so I just got done tweaking my brand new PC and explorer.exe still manages to be sluggish not as snappy as I'd like or expected at all. Specs are i7 4th gen processor, 16GB RAM, windows 7 64 home premium on 256GB SSD, secondary internal 2TB drive. I assumed system would be lightning fast, been doing a bunch of researching and switched out a lot of different settings including enabling/disabling indexing, turning pagefile on/off or placing it on separate drive, turning folder optimization options on/off.. changes have been minimal or none at all. Any further advice or anything I might be missing, besides a new/repair install? PC is literally 3 days old I don't feel like I need a new install at all

Comment: Turning your paging file completely off is a horrible idea.  At the very least it the page file should be placed on your secondary drive, and it should be at least 16GB, sounds like the problem is your configuration.

Comment: I have purchased an SSD and had it not function properly out of the box.  Since something wasn't quite right, and the performance was horrible compared to other SSD's I owned.  I didn't bother testing the SSD and just exchanged it, but depending on your SSD manufacturer try:
[Inte](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=18455)
[SanDisk](http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/9328)
[OCZ](http://ocz.com/consumer/download/firmware)
[Kingston](http://www.kingston.com/us/support/technical/downloads?product=SV300S3&filename=SSD_Toolbox_20)

Comment: is file access time slow as well? what kind of write speeds are you looking at for large files?

Comment: @web_dvlp_sd - does anything interesting show up in procmon? maybe filter to include explorer.exe and then set it to run at boot

Comment: @Ramhound: He has 16 GB RAM! Unless he plans on using more than that (I'm guessing not), it is actually very sensible to turn off paging. He won't need it and will save precious SSD disk space by disabling it. Even if he used it, why on earth would he waste 16 GB SSD space on a page file? If he needs to swap out 16 GB, he has a serious lack of RAM. Even if he did it, placing it on the SSD is problably the best solution as it is much faster than any secondary rotating disk he might have available.

Comment: @MatthewThepc - define interesting? it's a long-a$$ list and everytime I reach the bottom it starts to populate again

Comment: Also, different paging file scenarios haven't made any changes so I'm pretty sure that's not the cause of the lag

Comment: Which Windows do you use?

Comment: Windows 7 x64 Home Premium - Interesting behavior last night, uninstalled WinRAR and explorer went to normal again, had to reboot later and it went back to slow.

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem, it was 'Application hooks' for a program called 'Display Fusion' I'm running to manage my multiple display's. As soon as I disabled it Explorer went back to being snappy as hell. Hope this could be useful to somebody else, two days worth of trouble-shooting!

Answer (score 0):

One way to figure out what is going on is using Microsoft's [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) tool:

1. Open Process Monitor
2. Filter by process name "explorer.exe"
3. Perform the slow actions using explorer.exe
4. Open the "Stack Summary" tool in Process Monitor (found in the 'Tools' menu)
5. Sort by the time column
6. Unfold the tree of the time expensive operations. This will probably be many layers, and in case of disk slowness end up inside the kernel (the pink nodes) with significant time spent inside calls named stuff like "NtReadFile", "NtCreateFile", "fltmgr.sys" and similar (Google some of the method/file names to figure out what it's doing)

If it *is* related to disk I/O, I suggest installing the latest drivers from the disk vendor. This is especially relevant for SSD disks which is a relatively modern technology for which drivers are not completely stable yet.

Comment: Time column shows all zeros, also all drivers and windows updates are up-to-date, drivers updated using Uniblue DriverScanner

Comment: @web_dvlp_sd: Sounds odd. Even the fastest method calls should take *some* time. If no time measurements are shown for any application, then something is probably wrong. About "Uniblue DriverScanner", you might want to reconsider. See this link: http://www.mywot.com/en/scorecard/uniblue.com

Answer (score 0):

Your ssd should be in ahci mode and not ide.
Check your Starting Offset.
Download and run AS ssd benchmark to check the Starting Offset.
Partition Starting Offset my ssd is 1,048,576 bytes divide by 4096 = 256 which is normal if it was 256.4444 that would be no good.

There must 30 to 40% free disk space for GC and trim for ssd to run at maxium speeds.